# Intento abrir un modal pero no me funciona

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Buen día, tengo un modal el cual al hacer click en una imagen no se activa, la verdad ya revise el código  no encuentro el error. El código que uso es el mismo que ya había usado en otra ocasión pero ahora no me funciona. 
Si me pueden ayudar lo agradecería.

Esto esta en la vista _layout.cshtml

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showLogIn();">
    <img src="/Content/images/config.png" alt="Configurar Banner" title="Configurar Banner" />
</a>
```

Y este es mi modal:

```
<div class="modal fade fill-in" id="modalLogIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="pg-close"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <img src="http://www.vianney.com.mx/vianney/cenit/assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" data-src="http://www.vianney.com.mx/vianney/cenit/assets/img/logo.png" data-src-retina="http://www.vianney.com.mx/vianney/cenit/assets/img/logo.png" width="250">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div align="justify">
          <div class="login-container bg-white">
            <div class="p-l-50 m-l-20 p-r-50 m-r-20 p-t-50 m-t-30 sm-p-l-15 sm-p-r-15 sm-p-t-40">
              <h5>Solo Personal Autorizado</h5>
              <fieldset>
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                  <label>CORREO ELECTRONICO: </label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="ex. example.name@vianney.mx" class="form-control" required />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                  <label>CONTRASEÑA: </label>
                  <input type="password" id="contraseña" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="contraseña" required />
                </div>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons m-t-10" value="Ingresar" onclick="validar();" /><br /><br />
                <h4 id="msgError" class="text-danger bold font-montserrat"></h4>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Y esta es mi función:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function showLogIn() {
    $("#modalLogIn").modal();
}
function abrirEnPestana(url) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.href = url;
    a.click();
}
function validar() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
    var contraseña = document.getElementById("contraseña").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("LogIn_Admin", "Inicio")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {usuario:usuario, contraseña:contraseña},
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                //form.submitted = false;
                //form.submit();
                //window.location = "/Inicio/Vista_Admin_Banner"
                $('#modalLogIn').modal('hide');
                abrirEnPestana('@Url.Action("Vista_Admin_Banner", "Inicio")');
            } else {
                //form.submitted = false;
                $('#modalLogIn').modal('hide');
                $("#modalStickUpSmall").modal();
                //document.getElementById("msgError").innerHTML = "Error Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrectos";
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Debe ser $("#modalLogIn").modal("show");

Comment: El código está bien, algo más debe estar provocando la falla. ¿Qué te muestra la consola al dar click en la imagen?

Comment: @Xique en el script de la función

Comment: @Gerry a que te refieres con que me muestra?

Comment: Abre las herramientas de desarrollador en tu navegador y mira que muestra la consola al dar click en la imagen.

Comment: Por cierto, no relacionado con el error, pero te falta un `</div>` al final de tu modal.

Comment: @Gerry pues ya le puse el `</div>` y me marca que le hace falta una etiqueta de inicio. En la consola no me marca nada al dar click

Comment: El error es por que falta cerrar el `</script>`, tal como lo indica @Xique en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77279/intento-abrir-un-modal-pero-no-me-funciona#comment142300_77285).

Comment: @Gerry no, si lo tiene aquí fue un error de dedo :D

Comment: hola, si usas boostrap no es necesario usar js para abrir el modal

Comment: yo tambien tengo un error parecido al compañero, a mi lo que no me esta agarrando son las funciones, osea en el codigo como que no las enlaza y pasa al href que no tiene nada, decidi probar poniendo la funcion directa y si da or lo que esta buena. lo que pasa es que no la trae aun cuando ya esa enlazada, necesito ayuda con ello, ademas le doy inspeccionar y cuando pulso el boton dice que la funcion no esta delcara y mentira ya la tengo hecha, de verdad no se que pasa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muy bien, eh trabajado sobre tu código, y lo que buscas es que el cierre lo haga desde js.

Como mencionaron mis colegas, agregado a a la configuración de **data-target="#modalLogIn"** podrás abrirlo sin perder tú imagen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLogIn">
    <img src="/Content/images/config.png" alt="Configurar Banner" title="Configurar Banner" />
  </a>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>


Configuración del modal

    <div class="modal fade fill-in" id="modalLogIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
        <i class="pg-close"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <img src="http://www.vianney.com.mx/vianney/cenit/assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" data-src="http://www.vianney.com.mx/vianney/cenit/assets/img/logo.png" data-src-retina="http://www.vianney.com.mx/vianney/cenit/assets/img/logo.png" width="250">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div align="justify">
              <div class="login-container bg-white">
                <div class="p-l-50 m-l-20 p-r-50 m-r-20 p-t-50 m-t-30 sm-p-l-15 sm-p-r-15 sm-p-t-40">
                  <h5>Solo Personal Autorizado</h5>
                  <fieldset>
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                      <label>CORREO ELECTRONICO: </label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="ex. example.name@vianney.mx" class="form-control" required />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                      <label>CONTRASEÑA: </label>
                      <input type="password" id="contraseña" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="contraseña" required />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons m-t-10" value="Ingresar" onclick="validar();" /><br /><br />
                    <h4 id="msgError" class="text-danger bold font-montserrat"></h4>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      
    <script language="javascript">
        function showLogIn() {
        $("#modalLogIn").modal();
    }
    function abrirEnPestana(url) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.href = url;
        a.click();
    }
    function validar() {
        var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
        var contraseña = document.getElementById("contraseña").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("LogIn_Admin", "Inicio")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {usuario:usuario, contraseña:contraseña},
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    //form.submitted = false;
                    //form.submit();
                    //window.location = "/Inicio/Vista_Admin_Banner"
                    //$('#modalLogIn').modal('hide');
                    $( ".close").click();
                    abrirEnPestana('@Url.Action("Vista_Admin_Banner", "Inicio")');
                } else {
                    //form.submitted = false;
                    //$('#modalLogIn').modal('hide');
                    $( ".close").click();
                    $("#modalStickUpSmall").modal();
                    //document.getElementById("msgError").innerHTML = "Error Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrectos";
                }
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**$( ".close").click();** es la clave, ya que este botón ejecuta la función **data-dismiss="modal"** que es la que se encarga de desvanecer el modal, misma que esta configurado en tu html.

Comment: y con esto ya no genero un script?

Answer (score 2):

```js
    function showLogIn() {
    console.log("click")
        $("#modalLogIn").modal('show');
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="showLogIn()"> Boton</button>
<div class="modal fade fill-in" id="modalLogIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="pg-close"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <img src="http://www.vianney.com.mx/vianney/cenit/assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" data-src="http://www.vianney.com.mx/vianney/cenit/assets/img/logo.png" data-src-retina="http://www.vianney.com.mx/vianney/cenit/assets/img/logo.png" width="250">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div align="justify">
          <div class="login-container bg-white">
            <div class="p-l-50 m-l-20 p-r-50 m-r-20 p-t-50 m-t-30 sm-p-l-15 sm-p-r-15 sm-p-t-40">
              <h5>Solo Personal Autorizado</h5>
              <fieldset>
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                  <label>CORREO ELECTRONICO: </label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="ex. example.name@vianney.mx" class="form-control" required />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                  <label>CONTRASEÑA: </label>
                  <input type="password" id="contraseña" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="contraseña" required />
                </div>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons m-t-10" value="Ingresar" onclick="validar();" /><br /><br />
                <h4 id="msgError" class="text-danger bold font-montserrat"></h4>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Así debería ser tu function :

```
<script language="javascript">
    function showLogIn() {
        $("#modalLogIn").modal('show');
    }
<script>
```

Comment: ya lo he intentado de esta forma pero no me funciona

Comment: y con toggle ? $("#modalLogIn").modal('toggle');

Comment: @LuisAngelMezaPerez  "</script>"

Comment: No es necesario utilizar `.modal('show');`, ese es el valor por defecto de `modal`: [documentación](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#options)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba eliminando `onclick="showLogIn();"`.

Déjalo solo de esta manera:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="login">
  <img src="/Content/images/config.png" alt="Configurar Banner" title="Configurar Banner" />
</a>
```

Agrégale un `id` a tu modal ejemplo: `loginmodal`, y llámalo en tu `script` así:

```
$("#login").click(function () {
  $("#loginmodal").modal('show');
});
```

Comment: ya lo había probado de esta manera y tampoco

Comment: `.modal('show');` y `.modal();` dan el mismo resultado; referencia [aquí](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#options).

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la [documentación de Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage), puedes hacerlo simplemente con:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLogIn">
    <img src="/Content/images/config.png" alt="Configurar Banner" title="Configurar Banner" />
</a>
```

Comment: si esa es la Via data attributes, pero como el usaba un javascript...

Comment: Hay que buscar por todos los caminos posibles, ¿no lo crees? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hola ya que usas boostrap es mucho mas facil sin necesidad de usar JavaScript esto te puede ayudar:

```
<p class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Open Login Modal</a></p>
```

de esa manera podras abrir un modal la idea es usar esto:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal"
```

de esta manera indicaras que estas usando un modal.

Te dejare un ejemplo para que veas su funcionalidad:

```css
/* #####################################################################
   #
   #   Project       : Modal Login with jQuery Effects
   #   Author        : Rodrigo Amarante (rodrigockamarante)
   #   Version       : 1.0
   #   Created       : 07/28/2015
   #   Last Change   : 08/02/2015
   #
   ##################################################################### */
   
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#login-modal .modal-dialog {
    width: 350px;
}

#login-modal input[type=text], input[type=password] {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#div-login-msg,
#div-lost-msg,
#div-register-msg {
    border: 1px solid #dadfe1;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 28px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

#div-login-msg.success,
#div-lost-msg.success,
#div-register-msg.success {
    border: 1px solid #68c3a3;
    background-color: #c8f7c5;
}

#div-login-msg.error,
#div-lost-msg.error,
#div-register-msg.error {
    border: 1px solid #eb575b;
    background-color: #ffcad1;
}

#icon-login-msg,
#icon-lost-msg,
#icon-register-msg {
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dadfe1;
    margin-right: 5px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

#icon-login-msg.success,
#icon-lost-msg.success,
#icon-register-msg.success {
    background-color: #68c3a3 !important;
}

#icon-login-msg.error,
#icon-lost-msg.error,
#icon-register-msg.error {
    background-color: #eb575b !important;
}

#img_logo {
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
}

/* #########################################
   #    override the bootstrap configs     #
   ######################################### */

.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .8;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #ececec;
    border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
    border-radius: 0px;
    outline: 0;
}

.modal-header {
    min-height: 16.43px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 0px;
}

.checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn-lg, .btn-group-lg>.btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn-link {
    padding: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
    color: #95a5a6;
}

.btn-link:hover, .btn-link:focus {
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.glyphicon {
    top: 0px;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- BEGIN # BOOTSNIP INFO -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <h1 class="text-center">Modal Login with jQuery Effects</h1>
        <p class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Open Login Modal</a></p>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- END # BOOTSNIP INFO -->

<!-- BEGIN # MODAL LOGIN -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" align="center">
     <img class="img-circle" id="img_logo" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/logo.jpg">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </button>
    </div>
                
                <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
                <div id="div-forms">
                
                    <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                    <form id="login-form">
                  <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="div-login-msg">
                                <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-login-msg">Type your username and password.</span>
                            </div>
          <input id="login_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
          <input id="login_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                                </label>
                            </div>
               </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
                            </div>
             <div>
                                <button id="login_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                                <button id="login_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                            </div>
            </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End # Login Form -->
                    
                    <!-- Begin | Lost Password Form -->
                    <form id="lost-form" style="display:none;">
               <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="div-lost-msg">
                                <div id="icon-lost-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-lost-msg">Type your e-mail.</span>
                            </div>
          <input id="lost_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
               </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button id="lost_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                                <button id="lost_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                            </div>
            </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End | Lost Password Form -->
                    
                    <!-- Begin | Register Form -->
                    <form id="register-form" style="display:none;">
                  <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="div-register-msg">
                                <div id="icon-register-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-register-msg">Register an account.</span>
                            </div>
          <input id="register_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                            <input id="register_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                            <input id="register_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
               </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Register</button>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button id="register_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                                <button id="register_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                            </div>
            </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End | Register Form -->
                    
                </div>
                <!-- End # DIV Form -->
                
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
    <!-- END # MODAL LOGIN -->
```

me he dado cuenta que al momento de probar el codigo aqui en la pagina no funciona no se porque pero aqui esta el link de boostrap donde puede reforzar lo que te estoy diciendo aqui
[Modal Boostrap](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/modal-login-with-jquery-effects)

Comment: Nota: el codigo no funciona en la pagina y no se porque: Ver el link que deje. ami me funciona ese metodo

Comment: no agregue los efectos porque no son necesarios

Comment: gracias, deja lo checo :D

Comment: @AmairaniFernanda debes tener un poco de cuidado con boostrap varias librerias a la ves pueden hacer un grave daño, yo uso boostrap por eso te lo digo :3

Comment: si, muchas gracias :)

Comment: @AmairaniFernanda te sirvio ????